# Permissions restriction

Tags: permissions

- OWD on `Contact` is Internal Public Read/Write,
- OWD on `TEAS` object is "Controlled by Parent".

I have a profile that has read access to all contacts but edit access based on ownership hierarchy, and view all access to another object, "TEAS",

- Profile name is "Core User Profile". Profile is assigned to users.

have several users in the same profile, "Core User Profile", who need edit access to "score" field on all TEAS object records.

- I created a public group for these few users and created a sharing rule on Contact providing Read/Write access.
- I also created a Permission Set "Edit TEAS Permission" with Contact object settings permissions: `Read, Edit, View all` enabled and with `TEAS` object setting permissions: `Read, Create, Edit, View`

  - All enabled with edit access to the score field. Permission set is assigned to users.

When logging in as user who needs the edit access, I am still getting a privileges error.

*Note: we use the default contact record type. We do have another record type that will never have TEAS records.*